# Firebase cloud messaging (web) - Service worker stops and notifications are not delivered

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firefox, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

In my web app (react/typescript/vite), up until last week, everything was working fine.

Since today, in Firefox, only some notifications that i send to the specific app token are received, about 1 in 3.

I noticed that the service workers, including firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope are stopped. They stop on their own and sometimes start again, the stop, etc.

I know that the notifications are sent, because when i send the notifications to multiple tokens at the time, including the problematic Firefox version, and other browsers + android versions, all the clients except Firefox receive the notification.

No errors show up in the console at any time. The code was not edited between when it was working fine and now.

I tried:
Firefox: updating, uninstalling/reinstalling, reverting to older version, clearing cache, deleting authorizations and website data, using a new browser profile.
Other: updating all librairies

Tested on multiple computers aswell